# ¿Cómo unir dos tablas de diferentes base de datos en una declaración UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas estimados,

Me podrían ayudar con la siguiente consulta :

```
DB 1
Table1
id      registration      name    adrress    season
1        cv123cb            a         a        35
2        cv345cb            b         b        35
3        cv567cb            c         c        35
4        cv789cb            d         d        35


DB 2    
Table2
registration    name    adreess     season   idtable2
   cv123cb     a         a           35       
   cv345cb     b         b           35     
   cv567cb     c         c           35       
   cv789cb     d         d           35       


Need:

DB 2    
Table2
registration    name    adreess     season   idtable2
   cv123cb       a         a             35       1
   cv345cb       b         b             35       2 
   cv567cb       c         c             35       3
   cv789cb       d         d             35       4
```

Necesito que los ID pasen a la tabla 2 siempre y cuando los Campos `Registration`, `name` y `season` sean iguales.Espero haber pedido ayuda de la manera correcta, caso contrario me disculpo. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Por favor lee lo siguiente para mejorar tu pregunta: [ask]

Comment: Cuales son las diferentes bases de datos? queres una nueva table o solo un query?

Comment: Necesito un Query.Gracias estimado.

Comment: Puedes utilizar el Update con Join, y usar las tablas con una ruta absoluta (o mas absoluta), siendo por ejemplo [DataBase].[dbo].[TableName], Si las tablas son de distintos servidores deberás linkeralos con el [sp_addlinkedserver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql) y la ruta absoluta depende del alias que le des al servidor linkeado (seria [ServerAlias].[DataBase].[dbo].[TableName])

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tenes que hacer se puede hacer perfectamente "como" si fuera un select, pero usando la declaracion de un update.

De una forma generica seria algo asi:

```
UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TablaA A
JOIN TableB B
ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...
```

Y en tu caso en particular, seria algo asi (parado sobre la base de datos donde esta TABLE2):

```
UPDATE TABLE2
SET idtable2 = B.id
FROM Table2 A JOIN DB1.schema.Table1 AS B
ON A.registration = B.registration AND A.name = B.name AND A.adrress = B.adrress
```